# Sending commands to jar with c++

Tags: java, c++, winapi, command

I ran a .jar file (in c++) like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    system("java -jar filename.jar");
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** This runs perfectly just the way I want it, but how to I send commands to the jar app with c++ code? I know I can't do system("MyJavaAppCommand"); since that would just be executed by the windows command and not my app's. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example for sending comments?

Comment: Well I should mention that it is a minecraft server and after getting the jar up and running I would like to send commands like "save-all" it through c++ code

Comment: Does the minecraft server offer some API you can use to send it commands? If so, you should use that.

Answer (score 3):

I would try using command line arguments like

```
system("java -jar filename.jar arg1 arg2 ... argN");
```

There arguments are passed to your main method in

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Too many references to include here

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jar+command+line+arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can just add arguments after "filename.jar". These values will be seen by Java inside the `argc[]` array in the usual `public static void main(String argc[])` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might find pipes usefull.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780(v=vs.85).aspx